# convert a line plot to a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot

I connect several points two by two by

```
plot([x1,x2],[y1,y2]) %create line
% x1,y1 = coordinates of point 1
% x2,y2 = coordinates of point 2
```

and I would like to know if it's possible to keep this different links into a matrix to display them subsequently with imagesc or imshow (this matrix will also be useful to me outside the display later)

Comment: It's not clear what you expect to see. Can you please add some more information?

Comment: hum ok I try : for example I make a plot A(422,521) and B(428,521) and it gives me a line and I would like to save this line in a matrix (sorry I have trouble explaining what I imagine).

Comment: all plots that I make are plotting on an other image with `hold on`.
 if you want i would like to save the different plots as a single image

Comment: Please create a graphic manually (in `paint`, for example) and upload it for us. When you say "save the line" you mean a _handle_ to it? Or do you want all of your plots to have the same _color_?

Answer (score 0):

As long as I understand, you are trying to plot multiple "lines" in one plot without using `hold`.

You can use concatenation for this purpose as shown below:

```
plot([1 ;2 ],[1;2] );
xlim([1 6]);
ylim([1 6]);
```

[image]

```
plot([3 ;4 ],[3;4] )
xlim([1 6]);
ylim([1 6]);
```

[image]

```
plot([5 ;6 ],[5;6] );
xlim([1 6]);
ylim([1 6]);
```

[image]

Finally if you want to plot these all lines into one plot you can use concatenation in the second dimension.

```
plot([1 3 5 ; 2 4 6 ],[1 3 5 ; 2 4 6] );
```

[image]

In order to save it and make it again plot table you can store in matrix with another dimension

```
matrixTest(:,:,1) = [1 3 5 ; 2 4 6 ];
matrixTest(:,:,2) = [1 3 5 ; 2 4 6 ];
plot(matrixTest(:,:,1),matrixTest(:,:,2));
```

[image]